# Python a secure way to get the database access?

Tags: python

I'm having some doubts about how can I "secure" the database's information to connect.
There is someway that I can get the access to the database in a more secure way? A Rest Api?
Or if someone can tell me a more secure that sending the access on the code

Thanks in advance

```
config = {
    'user': 'user',
    'password': 'password.',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'database': 'files_to_check',
    'raise_on_warnings': True,
}

try:
    # Try to connect to database
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)


    # Pointer of the sql
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    # Query to get the files from the database
    query = ("SELECT filename FROM filenames")
    queryhash = ("SELECT hash FROM filenames")

    # Execute the query
    cursor.execute(query)

    # select all the filenames from database
    # array to fill with the files from the database
    files_to_check = [str(row[0]) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
    cursor.close()

    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute(queryhash)
    # array to fill with the hash from the database
    hash_to_check = [str(row[0]) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

# Error definition on connection
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    # Check username and password
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("[*] Username or password are invalid")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        # Check if database that are connection exists
        print("[*] Database does not exist")
    else:
        print(err)
else:
    cnx.close()
```

Comment: What do you consider "secure"? What's your goal? If you want to get credentials out of the source code, the idiomatic thing to do is create a configuration file and read that in, like `config.json` and then in code `config = json.load(open("config.json"))`

Comment: Not to go on the source code
Sorry, let me try to explain better
This is part of an app that is to be distributed by lets imagine 50 people, and I didn't want that they could access the database information by reverse engineering or something

Comment: But the host is a the `'localhost'`?

Comment: Check this question out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981064/safeguarding-mysql-password-when-developing-in-python

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, that it's just to try locally to apply on a real database

Comment: @Benloper Thank you, I will check it

Comment: @ShwSvn: Then I would connect over aan `ssh` connection. Those are "supposed" to be quite secure. You first install the public key in a secure manner on the server, and then you can communicate over an encrypted channel the database credentials.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing your question is how to not have to include the DB information (host, port, password, etc.) in the code. I would say the two easiest ways are:

- Environment variables
- Separate configuration files

### Environment variables

```
import os

config = {
    'user': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
    'password': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'host': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
    'database': os.getenv('DB_DATABASE'),
    'raise_on_warnings': os.getenv('DB_DATABASE', 'true') == 'true',
}
```

### Configuration file

```
import json

with open('config.json') as file:
    config = json.load(file)
```

Comment: @ShwSvn: you need to take steps at the OS level to secure the config file.

Comment: If you require a separate config file, you can just not distribute it anywhere, and people will have to build their own. This makes sense because everyone will have different credentials to put in

Comment: @ShwSvn what is the use case here? Who is going to use the script and to which database are they connecting?

Comment: But they won't have different credentials, because all of them are going to use the same table with the same data

Comment: @PacoH. it is a client side anti-cheat for a game that is going to check for the files on the folder, for same files on the database.
The app will connect to the database, save the data from the table on an array and check with the files on the folder or each person

Comment: @ShwSvn: will all users have the same files? If yes, what's to stop them sharing files thereby avoiding your anti-cheat scheme?

Comment: @mhawke Yes they are suppose to have the same files, the anti-cheat is to check if any of them changed/added some file
How so sharing files?

Comment: @ShwSvn In this case I would create two different components: a web server that has a public API endpoint that takes a file hash that the web server then looks up in the database. This way the DB credentials only have to be in your web server to which only you have access. The second part would the anti-cheat client that the users would have on their machines. This client sends the file hashes to the web server api endpoint, therefore they don't need the DB credentials.

Comment: @ShwSvn: sorry, your anti-cheat description was not clear to me. You are trying to prevent file tampering? Paco's idea seems reasonable, i.e. send file hashes to a service on your server to detect altered files. Anyway, it's a bad idea to give public access to your database, so writing your own web service avoids that requirement. You can use something like [`flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [`bottle`](https://bottlepy.org) for a lightweight and easy to implement service.

Comment: @PacoH. Thank you it was that I was searching to know if it is a way to do it
Just two questions, I can do the web api using python and if yes using what?

Comment: @mhawke yes file tampering and adding more files that can be cheats
Sorry for my bad description, I have some difficult explaining

Comment: @ShwSvn The simplest way to do the web server with one endpoint in python would be [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Comment: @PacoH. Thanks :) I will try it

Comment: And Thanks everyone for your anwsers

Comment: @PacoH.
Can you please check?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422150/python-with-flask-connect-to-api

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use an external config file to store the user, password, and other sensitive information.

Then use your operating system's permission system to restrict access to that file such that your application can read the file, but other unprivileged users can not.

Also make sure that you use a SSL connection to the database.

You should also look at authentication plugins.